# is this a bug of vim? vit leaves out the last char

Tags: vim

In vim (v7.4.521, both windows and linux) when typing vit on these lines:

```
<code>"hello world!"</code>  <-- straight quote
<code>“hello world!”</code>  <-- curly quote
<code>hello world!—</code>  <-- emdash
```

the 1st is ok, "hello world!" is hi-lighted. But with the 2nd and 3rd, only “hello world!(”) or hello world!(—) is highlighted, the last char in each case is left out. Seems this only happens when the last char is speical. Google didn't help. Any idea?

Comment: Check to make sure you are using UTF-8 everywhere. It sounds like the multi-byte characters in the second two characters aren't being properly recognized. `vit` properly selects all characters for me.

Comment: yes I use utf-8 everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this with Vim 7.4.542. The behavior seems to depend on having `:set selection=exclusive`. I guess it doesn't properly account for the fact that the last character consists of more than one byte.

<strike>Please submit a bug report to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).</strike> Christian Brabandt has [posted a patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/vJ38pt73e_E/8taY3XZX5pcJ) already, thanks!

Edit: And it's already incorporated in version 7.4.547!

Comment: This only happens when selection is exclusive and only in visual mode, right?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Yes, I think so; `cit` and `dit` work fine. Thanks for noticing and already providing a patch! (Otherwise, I would have informed vim_dev later.)

Comment: Patch 7.4.547 fixed only vit, but same problem still remains with `vi(`, `vi[` and `vi{`. Please report this bug; I can't post to vim-dev@vim.org even after I subscribed to vim-dev-subscribe@vim.org.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Other text objects still seem to suffer from this (see @avalan_che's comment); I can reproduce this with Vim 7.4.729, again with `:set selection=exclusive` and visual mode. It would be great if you could extend your patch to those, too!

Comment: @avalan_ch I didn't see a message in the moderation queue. To all others, can you please post an example that is going wrong? Thanks

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: To reproduce, take one of the question's examples, and replace `<code>` with another delimiter, e.g. `(“hello world!”)` (note the typographical quotes), and then use `vi(`. The ending quote isn't selected; that's the bug.

Comment: @avalan_che: Included as Patch 7.4.847 so problem should now be fixed.